How do I measure 'one year bias stability' in a MEMS gyroscope?
SBG tells what's the one year bias stability, but how do i measure this error parameter?

What I want to know is, what formula does SBG use to calculate this error parameter? I'm not concerned about how to simulate aging.

well, how do you determine the measurement offset of a ruler? You measure a lot of things that you know the precise length of, and then find out whether the measurements have an offset. Same as with any other error measurement – can you maybe specify the question a bit more? Is this more about the question of how to determine offsets in general, or specifically for gyroscopes, or is it about how you simulate the yearly offset, or about something else?

I want to know how caculate the one year bias stability for IMU including accelerometer and gyroscope.

that's not more specific, that's just repeating what you already said!

Sorry. What I want to know is, what formula does SBG use to calculate this error parameter? I'm not concerned about how to simulate aging.

You measure the bias for a large number of gyroscopes, and measure them all again after a year.
Since you usually don't want to wait for a year, you could use some methods to simulate the aging. This simulation may or may not be accurate, depending on the type of application they will be used in.
Generally, the main contributors to such errors tend to be:

degradation due to on/off cycling, which you can simulate easily. Some devices degrade when they are kept on continuously, and a rare few degrade if they are kept off. For those, you really only can wait.

degradation due to temperature cycling. This could be the day/night cycle, or other on/off cycles. This can be simulated by exposing the device to an equal number of temperature cycles. Note that it makes a difference whether the device is on or off during the cycles, and if the cycles are very short the response of the materials could be qualitatively different from gradual changes.

degradation due to material fatigue caused by vibrations and shocks. I would expect this to be an important contributor to a gyroscope. Can be simulated with shakers, for example, exposing the device to about the same kind of vibration load as one would expect over a year. There exist other instruments which can generate high G shocks.

degradation due to usual wear and tear. This is probably harder to simulate accurately, but there may be established protocols to create similar effects.


In general, if you're using these devices for some critical application, you would need to check what kind of test protocols are needed for that application. Aerospace applications would probably also add vaccum testing, for instance, and much more violent thermal excursions and and vibrations and shocks.
These protocols are generally published and available, even if hard to find and know which one exactly you need to use.
If you're asking about the protocols used by device manufacturers to test for data sheet numbers, I don't actually know. I suspect there will be some IEC or JEDEC standard for each type of device, what needs to be tested, and at what loads. Often, when this is a real concern, MIL standards are a good place to start.

Thank you for your detailed answer. But I'm still not clear on how this parameter is calculated. I think it's the difference between the bias of the first time and the bias of the second time(after one year aging simulation). I'm not sure if my understanding is correct.

Yes, the difference is essentially what is calculated. The actual number is a statistical measure, though. If you measure the bias drift over one year for one device, you don't get the full picture. It will be done for a number of devices, and you'll essentially report the expected drift based on all the results. I don't know what the norm is, and what each company does, but I expect it will be a number calculated as some multiple of the standard deviation of the absolute value of drift across atleast a hundred devices drawn from different manufacturing batches.


What I want to know is, what formula does SBG use to calculate this error parameter?

Bad news is: for the actual precise formula, you'll have to ask them.
But what probably happened is this:
They model the offset of each sensor a random variable with a known distribution. Then they simply take a sensor, measure known values, to get a sample offset, and use that (together with their random model) as estimate of the offset error before the aging.
Then they age the sensor.
Then they do the same measurements again, and get a different offset error estimate. They note down the difference between the estimate before, and after aging.
They do this not only for one sensor, but for many sensors. So, they get a statistic for how the difference in errors is distributed.
They then go and find another stochastic model, but this time not for the offset, but for the offset difference (between before and after aging, for each sensor individually). They fit the parameters of that model to the observed differences, and calculate the highest difference that you would realistically see, e.g., if you buy 10 million sensors.
Why you'd need to ask them and they probably won't tell you in detail how they calculated this: They would need to tell you the mathematical models they used for their sensor offset, and for the offset change. That, and buying a couple dozen sensors, would allow you to infer on what they optimize their sensor production for, and under which condition they will sort out a sensor because it has a significant probability to violate their offset stability conditions.
(They can't age all the sensors in the factory to test that, so they need to look at the things you can measure without the aging, look at how they relate to the offset change, and then write down a rule that says "OK, if the offset is larger than this and that, and the thermal dependency is worse than this and that but voltage sensitivity is better than this and that, you must throw away the sensor, it will possibly fail to perform as specified in the customer's device, and then the customer will not buy from us again". And the customer would be right – BSG would have a quality problem. BSG probably does that testing, and bins their sensors accordingly, to not sell you a sensor that is worse than what the datasheet says.)
That knowledge  of how their sensors are tested and which part of the tested sensors they sell and which not, that is worth a lot to them – it allows their competitors to build similarly reliable sensors, without having to do the same amount of characterization. And remember, characterization required a lot of chips to be aged for a lot of time, and they'll do that regularly to notice any variation in production. That gives them a product cost factor, and giving away that info to the competition would mean they are then at a disadvantage. Of course, if you're a large customer (say, you buy 10 million chips to build them into cars), this might be negotiable, under non-disclosure agreements.
You can, and should, probably, actually ask, though! The question whether they model the bias error difference as normal, two-sided exponential or anything else probably isn't a secret, but well-known in the industry, so they might tell you the general procedure without giving you the actual numbers you need to do the same calculation for their sensors.
If you don't get a response: assume normal (Gaussian) i.i.d. for all variables as a working hypothesis, and see whether some observables cluster well with the offset change in your own large-scale measurement.
If you don't have many sensors, you can't do a statistic, so you can't do that measurement yourself.
